# Drupal 7 LDAP integration

Tags: php, apache, drupal, ldap, drupal-7

When installing Drupal 7 module http://drupal.org/project/ldap, I get the error.

> No LDAP Extension is loaded for PHP, so LDAP will not work properly.
>   (Currently using LDAP Extension Loaded Failed)

Does this mean I have to install the ldap extension for PHP? If so, how do I do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you do need to install the extension

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

in terminal ought to do it. I imagine an Apache restart will be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Installation on Windows

1. Find php_ldap.dll which is generally under the PHP/ext folder.
2. Open php.ini (inspect `phpinfo()` for exact location of this file).
3. Ensure the extension_dir key is pointing to the extensions folder found in step 1. E.g. `extension_dir="C:\php\ext"`.
4. Remove the comment on the line that contains `extension=php_ldap.dll`.
5. Save the file and restart the web server. Recheck `phpinfo()` for the ldap extension.